# Хранение JSON данных в SQLite

Tags: java, sql, json, sqlite

У меня есть массив JSON объектов.

```
objects_array = [ obj0, obj1, obj2, ... ]
```

Ключи в объектах -- это, естественно, строки, а вот значениями может выступать все что угодно, включая двоичные данные, вложенные объекты, массивы.

Например, `obj0 = objects_array[0]` может быть таким:

```
{
    k1: "text",
    k2: 123,
    k3: Image, // бинарное изображение
    k4: {
      ... // вложенный объект
    },
    k5: [ 123, "string", { ... }, [ ... ], ... ]
}
```

В то время как у `obj1` могут быть абсолютно другие ключи и значения.

Каким образом можно сохранить это в базу данных SQLite?

**Возможные решения:**

I

Хранить объекты как строки.

II

Оптимально ли будет создавать для каждого объекта свою таблицу?

III

Есть идея хранить всё это в одной таблице следующем образом.

Таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE `objects` (
    `id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `key`   TEXT,
    `type`  TEXT,
    `value` BLOB
);
```

Далее мы переводим все пути к примитивным значениям в строки. Полученная строка -- key, тип значения -- type, значение -- value.

Например для этого объекта `obj2 = objects_array[2]`:

```
{
    k1: "text",
    k2: 123.22,
    k3: Image,
    k4: {
      kk1: 222
    },
    k5: [ 123, "string", { kkk: 333 }, [1, 2, 3] ]
}
```

Будет составлен следующий список ключей, типов и значений для таблицы `objects`:

```
objects_array.2.k1       | "string" | "text"
objects_array.2.k2       | "number" | 123.22
objects_array.2.k3       | "blob"   | Image
objects_array.2.k4.kk1   | "number" | 222
objects_array.2.k5.0     | "number" | 123
objects_array.2.k5.1     | "string" | "string"
objects_array.2.k5.2.kkk | "number" | 333
objects_array.2.k5.3.0   | "number" | 1
objects_array.2.k5.3.1   | "number" | 2
objects_array.2.k5.3.2   | "number" | 3
```

Насколько это практично?

IV

[Couchbase Lite](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android).

**UPD**

**Дргие детали**

1. Пишу под андроид на `Java`.
2. Весь объект редко когда бывает необходим. Чаще всего придется искать значения конкретных полей у объектов: `objects_array.*.finded_key*`.

Comment: может вам взглянуть на MongoDB - для этой БД это более натуральный формат хранения, по-моему...

Comment: @MaxU, я пишу под андроид.

Comment: Что мешает вам просто хранить JSON (строки), а разбирать после выборки? Универсальней не придумаешь.

Comment: тогда посмотрите в сторону CouchDB

Comment: Тут вопрос в том, что вы дальше собираетесь делать с этими данными. Вам необходим поиск по ключам/значениям - тогда последний вариант похож на правду, только типы данных лучше хранить в виде ID типа, а еще лучше выносить в словарь (если это возможно). Если же данные нужно чаще отображать целиком - то лучше сделать таблицу с структурой где каждому ключу соответствует колонка. Если же вам и далее нужен json - то его можно хранить как текст. Все 3 варианта при желании (для быстродействия) можно комбинировать (правда при этом получаем избыточность, со всеми вытекающими)

Comment: @PinkTux, мне кажется это будет слишком меделенно. Весь объект редко когда бывает необходим. Чаще всего придется искать значения конкретных полей у объектов: `objects_array.*.finded_key*`.

Comment: @MaxU, CouchDB нужен сервер?

Comment: @Mike, не понял фразу "выносить в словарь"

Comment: Заводите что то типа "типы объектов", для каждого типа заводите в таблице "поля типа" какие в нем бывают ключи и каких они типов данных. В таблице объектов каждому объекту указываете его тип а в таблице с данными хранится только id-обекта, id-ключа, значение (того типа, который в словаре). Как то так, только опять же возможна масса вариантов, который можно выбирать только полностью понимая все тонкости задачи, проанализировав все возможные данные которые когда либо поступят и все методы работы с ними. В итоге напишите на SQLite свою Mongo :)

Comment: @Mike, мечтаю о `MongoLite`  :D

Comment: @SergeyPestov, я не знаю может ли Couchbase Lite (версия для Android) работать без сервера... Почитайте [здесь](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.1.0/develop/training/build-first-android-app/index.html)

Comment: @MaxU, посмотрел. Couchbase Lite может работать без сервера: https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android. Скорее всего попробую, но `SQLite`, мне кажется, будет надежнее.